# Download file with random name and execute

Tags: powershell

MSI Generator - Downloads custom-named MSI, and I need to download and execute.

I can download and specify a saved file name, but I can't get passed that.

So, this special URL creats a custom MSI file to download, e.g. `Installer_t493ht.msi` (the random part of that changes each time). I'm trying to use PowerShell to download this file to a specific directory, assign the file name to a variable, and then execute.

What I have so far is:

```cs
$url = "https://UrlThatGeneratesRandomlyNamedMSI"
$output = "c:\SaveToThisDirectory\"

Import-Module BitsTransfer 

$job += Start-BitsTransfer -Source $url -Destination $output

while ($job | Where-Object {$job.JobState -eq "Transferring"}) {
    Sleep -Seconds 1
}

Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList '/I /qn $output/$RandomName.msi REBOOT=ReallySuppress'
```

Comment: Variables are expanded only inside of a double-quoted string.

Comment: Side note: why don't you just define a specific output file name? `$output = "c:\SaveToThisDirectory\myinstaller.msi"`. That way you won't have to deal with a random file name.

Answer (score 0):

Just add something like:

```
$msiFile = Get-Item -Path "$output\Installer_*.msi"
```

Than execute that (make sure you use double quotes, so the variabele gets expanded):

```
Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList "/I /qn $($msiFile.FullName) REBOOT=ReallySuppress"
```